# Get elapsed time since application start

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, timer

I am porting an app from ActionScript3.0 (Flex) to C# (WPF).AS3.0 has got a handy utility called [getTimer()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getTimer%28%29) which returns time since Flash Virtual machine start in milliseconds.I was searching in C# through classes as

```
DateTime
DispatcherTimer
System.Diagnostics.Process
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
```

but found nothing like this.It seems a very basic feature to me.For example Unity3D which runs on Mono has something familiar. Do I miss some utility here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartTime` is your friend.

..so to get elapsed time since start:

```
DateTime.UtcNow - Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartTime.ToUniversalTime()
```

alternatively, if you need more definition, `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` might be preferable. If so, start a stopwatch when your app starts:

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
```

then query the `sw.Elapsed` property during your execution run.

Comment: Whether to choose one or the other is not a matter of precision but of needs instead. `Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartTime` will never be called at the same time of `Stopwatch.StartNew()`! So it depends on when the user want to start timing. :)

Comment: Are you sure Process.GetCurrentProcess returns time since the Application starts up? I just made a check: (DateTime.Now -Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartTime).TotalSeconds  .At the moment the App is up I print the time to Console.It starts from 16-17 seconds.It is obviously too much because it took maximum 4 seconds for the App to start.

Comment: Interesting. The docs seem to agree with me. If this really is the case, I'd say it merits a new question.

Comment: @MichaelIV - the large amount of time is pretty easy to replicate. Press F5. To get a concistently small amount of time, use CTRL + F5 (Start without Debugging). F5 (Run with Debugger) runs inside a AssemblyName.vshost.exe which maybe have been running longer than when you first 'start' your debugging session. Try using Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName at the stdart of the program.

Comment: Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartTime doesnt work for me. Im not on Unity by the way. Stopwatch worked for me.

Comment: can this be used for determining total time across all session or only current active session

Comment: Stopwatch is much more reliable, DateTime.UtcNow - Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartTime.ToUniversalTime() is not reliable, because user may modify system time.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class Runtime
{
    static Runtime() 
    {
        var ThisProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess(); LastSystemTime = (long)(System.DateTime.Now - ThisProcess.StartTime).TotalMilliseconds; ThisProcess.Dispose();
        StopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch(); StopWatch.Start();
    }
    private static long LastSystemTime;
    private static System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch StopWatch;

    //Public.
    public static long CurrentRuntime { get { return StopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + LastSystemTime; } }
}
```

Then call: **Runtime.CurrentRuntime** to get the current programs runtime in miliseconds.

**Note**: You can replace the **TotalMilliseconds**/**ElapsedMilliseconds** to any other time metric you need.