# C# - Total Seconds expended since beginning of app use - data type

Tags: c#

(I'm considering building a game where one element is dependent on total time expended every second a game is run - not just since application start.)

What type would be most appropriate? For: storing the total seconds elapsed from the first time the app is used (and additive through time, every time the app is used subsequently) ?

Note, this is different than time since the first time the app is run, as presumably there would be some downtime when the app is not being run.

This stored value is updated every N seconds as the app runs. Note: this is about total usage of time in the game.

I was considering every frame, but that's probably excessive.

Would any issues arise if the comparison is made excessively?

Would DateTime comparison be off due to time zones, and less performant than just storing a seconds count in a simpler data type?

--

Please reopen:

**I clarified that I'm trying to find not the time since application session start but the total time used in the app since the beginning of all uses. I don't think GetCurrentProcess() or StopWatch do that - as they only seem to work for tracking the current session? [I don't believe this is a correct duplicate in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161088/get-elapsed-time-since-application-start). **

Comment: Why not just store the first time (as a `DateTime`) and calculate the difference when needed?

Comment: Are you interested in only whole seconds? (Integers)

Comment: If you want to make sure your variable won't reach its max value, you still can store the timestamps of run/exit each time it's run

Comment: @BrootsWaymb one consideration is that that approach is based on the system clock, which isn't necessarily stable.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb would that also be dependent to time zone changes?

Comment: downvote / close reason - please explain

Comment: `int.MaxValue` is 68 years, so you can't go wrong either way.

Comment: Use a long.   That will give you enough seconds to last for 300 billion years.  If you need more, ulong will get you twice that.

Comment: Both `float` and `int` occupy 4 bytes of memory. So from a memory standpoint, it doesn't matter which you use. In general, you should choose the datatype based on the values you will be storing. If you're saving fractional seconds, you'd choose float (although truthfully, I'd use `long`/`ulong` in this case and store the value in milliseconds). If you're storing the value as whole seconds, use `int`. Or, as others have said, use `DateTime` and compute elapsed time.

Comment: Any reason to only use 32 bits?

Comment: To be fair, my comment really won't work if you only want to capture time when the app is actively running (if not, your solution of updating a variable ever N seconds won't work - can't update while you're not running anything). And to add to  @canton7's reply, you'd definitely have to take steps to combat cheating with the local system clock (if you care), but that's a whole other can of worms I won't open.

Comment: .NET already has a type that represents durations, [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.7.2).  The [DateTime subtraction operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.op_subtraction?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns a TimeSpan. Subtract the current process's `StartTime` from the current time to get the uptime as a TimeSpan

Comment: I clarified that I'm trying to find not the time since application session start but the total time used in the app since the beginning. I don't think GetCurrentProcess() or StopWatch do that - as they only seem to work for tracking the current session?

Comment: @ina adding every *current sessions* will give you the total time

Comment: As @PanagiotisKanavos mentions, the difference of two `DateTime`s is a `TimeSpan`.  TimeSpan has a TotalSeconds property.  All you need to do is figure out when you want to measure things, get `DateTime.Now` at those times, do a subtraction and figure out the seconds

Comment: @cid i'm still not clear how to implement that. are you storing the elapsed time somehow (if so, which data type), or is there some sort of built in method that is able to know how much time the app has run in total across all sessions?

Comment: @flydog57 is there a way to do that without having to store data persistently? by "that" i mean total time (say, seconds) across all active sessions.

Comment: @ina The type is TimeSpan

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by "how much time the app has run in total across all sessions" and "the total time used in the app since the beginning".  But, `TimeSpan` represents, well, a time span (i.e. how much time has elapsed between two events in time).  Since you can get one by subtracting two `DateTime`s, it are easy to calculate.

Comment: @ina - Just use a long to track your total time elapsed and increment it with a timer at a duration that makes sense.  That will work fine.  Storing and adding a series of  timespans isn't the best approach for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i think you have misunderstood my question completely. i'm asking not about time difference since the user first ran the app, but the total time elapsed during ALL active sessions.

Comment: What is a "session"?  What is "the beginning".  If you mean "I want to track how long the user has been running my app by summing up all the time he spent during each run of the application, well, then you will need to persist it somewhere.  Use whatever persistence mechanism you like.  When I track stuff like this in a desktop app, I generally write out a user data/settings XML file to Isolated Storage (so no one knows where it is)

Comment: @ina which means *what*? What sessions? On which stack? Sessions have a specific meaning in ASP.NET for example. In many applications a single user isn't supposed to have multiple active sessions

Comment: You need to explain what "total time elapsed during ALL active sessions", "how much time the app has run in total across all sessions" and "the total time used in the app since the beginning" means.  We can't tell what you are asking.  Is your app a multi-user app?  Does it run on a server, on a desktop.  What libraries are you using?  Do you have any persistence set up in your app

Comment: @ina in any case why not just store a session's start time somewhere? The duration is the difference between the current time and the stored start. There's no need to *convert* that to seconds

Comment: okay i've updated the question and clarified again some more.

Comment: @ina a Stopwatch *is* a good choice too. It's not an active class, it stores the value of the high precision tick counter when its `Start` method is called. You can't get more accurate timing than that. Its `Elapsed` property returns the difference between the current tick count and the one when it was created.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i'm new to the timespan/duration concept. how would a conditional comparison be made? was thinking that certain things would only happen after a certain total time has been spent, and just using a float/int to mark the minimum. would a conversion be needed?

Comment: `if (TimeSpanObject.TotalSeconds > (double)TheMinimumTimeMarked) { ... }` Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalseconds?view=netframework-4.7.2) or [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.timespan.seconds?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: When the app starts, read the "time (in seconds) expended before this run" from somewhere (say an XML file in Isolated Storage).  If it's not there, set the value to 0.  Then get the value of `var timeAtStartOfRun = DateTime.Now`.  Every second the game runs calculate `prevTimeInSeconds + (DateTime.Now - timeAtStartOfRun).TotalSeconds`.  When the user quits the app, save that calculated time as the "time expended before this run" so it's there for the next time

Comment: would it be easier to just have things be stored as seconds (float) to avoid having to do all these type conversions?

Comment: Sure, store seconds if you like. Just start a stopwatch when the session starts (`private Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch(); stopwatch.Start();`), stop it when the session ends (`stopwatch.Stop();`), and then store the total seconds (`stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds`) however you want (file/database/registry/etc). Just be sure to add the previous total to the current elapsed seconds before you store it.